# How much faster is shallow rendering than mounting a component

Tags: javascript, testing, rendering, enzyme

Javascript (actually Typescript) project where tests are written with enzyme. We have 1000+ tests and `shallow` is not used only once --we always use `mount`.

Tests are starting to take longer to run, and I know that a good amount of our tests do no require to `mount` the component. `shallow` would suffice. In this scenario I ask myself: is it worth to use `shallow` whenever possible to reduce the amount of time that tests need to run?

I have been looking around, trying to find a quantitative comparison between `mount` and `shallow` but have been unable to find such a thing. In other words: if my best scenario is to save 1% of time I will not spend time on this. But if I can speed up my tests by, say, a 20%, then I will probably want to do it.

Do you have any insight into this topic, or know about any quantification on this topic?

**TL;DR:** I know the difference between `mount` and `shallow`. I know that `shallow` is faster than `mount`. The question is **how much faster** is `shallow` in comparison to `mount` (depends on many things... I am talking about some estimates)